# A property of permutation codes

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, binary

For $k\ge2$ and $M\ge k+2$ two integers, a permutation code matrix $C$ is a $\binom Mk\times M$ matrix which columns contain all distinct permutations of $M-k$ zeroes and $k$ ones.

Page 44 of his [work](http://www.commsys.isy.liu.se/publications/Theses/Theses:Dahlin:1103623317.13.pdf#page=44),
Dahlin writes that for different rows $x$ and $y$ of $C$ there are $\binom{M-2}{k-1}$ coordinates in which
$x$ has a one and $y$ has a zero, and vice versa.

How can one prove this? Is there a paper on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom Mk$ permutations of $k$ ones and $M-k$ zeroes. This is clear because this corresponds to the number of ways one can chose $k$ elements in a set of $M$, these elements being the positions of the ones.

Now consider the rows $x$ and $y$. They contain the value of $x^{\text{th}}$ and $y^{\text{th}}$ elements in the different permutations. If the $x^{\text{th}}$ element of a permutation is $1$ and the $y^{\text{th}}$ is $0$ or vice-versa, we have $M-2$ places left and $k-1$ ones left, so there are $\binom{M-2}{k-1}$ permutations verifying these conditions.

Comment: sorry I cannot follow your thought -- does your two occurrence of $x^{th}$ refer to the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they do ? The row $x$ contains the values of $\sigma(x)$ where $\sigma$ are the permutations. $\sigma(x)$ is what I call the $x^{\text{th}}$ element.